# I've accidently run chmod -R 600 / on ubuntu AWS Server

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, root, recursive

I've accidently run chmod -R 600 / on ubuntu AWS Server. Tried stopping it but didn't happen. Is there a way by which I can atleast backup my data present in the server.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm running out of time. If the server log me out I can't even log myself back in as the server won't allow login from ubuntu user anymore. Please help

Comment: Boot the rescue system of your server, mount your system and back up your data.

Comment: There is nothing that can "revert" a chmod command. Do as @GeraldSchneider suggested

Comment: How to do that in ubuntu hosted on AWS server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Spin up another instance.
- Mount the disk from the damaged instance on to a non root mount point (e.g. /mnt).
- Backup your data
- Recover to a new instance

Comment: Are you sure that's going to work? As the permissions are infected right now

Comment: Yes it will work, mounting the `broken` volume on a non root mount point will not affect the clean newly setup instance. You can then back it up and/or try to fix the permissions. I'd start with something like  `find /broken_mount_point -type d -exec chmod u+x {} \;` and work from there.

Comment: Still unable to access any file. Says permission denied on every command even cd

Comment: Got it working by following some directions from other questions. Thanks guys @Unbeliever and hangin-on-in-quiet-desperation. Specially for the confidence in such a crazy situation.